# Bookmarks into points of a single mp3 recording

Tags: mp3

I have some lectures recorded and would like to add names to different parts / points in the lecture, so that I can play parts separately.

Every lecture is recorded as a single mp3 file.

Is there anything in the format that supports such markings?
Is there a software that would work with such markings?

Comment: For example, I would love to have something like: [00:00 -12:30] Intro [12:31 - 28:10] Core issue 1 [28:11 - 44:00] Core issue 2 [44:01 - end] Summary. And than the ability to play certain part or parts by name

Comment: Use cue: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cue_sheet_%28computing%29

Comment: @IporSircer "An entire multi-track audio CD may be ripped to a single audio file and a cue sheet. However, software audio players and hardware digital audio players often treat each audio file as a single playlist entry, which can make it difficult to select and identify the individual tracks. A common solution is to split the original audio file into a series of separate files, one per track."

Comment: Apple seems to be more friendly to this...  https://www.startpage.com/do/search?query=create+chapters+in+mp3+files&cat=web&pl=chrome&language=english

Comment: Cue sheets as mentioned would be used for CD burning so you could get the burning program to separate the CD into tracks. If you are looking to use the single mp3 and immediately jump to a specific point I don't think that's possible. However you could use free software such as Audacity to cut the mp3 file into pieces and save them as separate mp3 files which will do the job you are trying to do. https://sourceforge.net/projects/audacity/

Comment: Thanks everybody, and, I'm still looking for more suggestions.